# how to avoid ConcurrentModificationException for listen once listener case

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling

Having a mEventMap to hold the listeners for different events, and has addListener() to register the eventlistener, removeListener(), and dispatchEvent() to the registered listeners.

```
public void addListener(EventListener listener) {
    synchronized (mEventMap) {

        List<WeakReference<EventListener<Event>>> listeners = mEventMap.get(listener.mEventClass);
WeakReference<EventListener<Event>> listenerRef = new WeakReference<>(
                (EventListener<Event>) listener)
        …
        listeners.add(listenerRef);

        …
    }
```

}

```
public void removeListener(EventListener listener) {
    synchronized (mEventMap) {
        List<WeakReference<EventListener<Event>>> listeners = mEventMap.get(listener.mEventClass);

        …
        if (contains(listeners, listener)) {
                doRemove(listeners, listener);
            }
       …

    }
}


public boolean dispatchEvent(Event event) {
synchronized (mEventMap) {
    List<WeakReference<EventListener<Event>>> listeners = mEventMap.get(event.getClass());
    ListIterator<WeakReference<EventListener<Event>>> listenerIterator = listeners.listIterator(listeners.size());
    …
    while (listenerIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            WeakReference<EventListener<Event>> listenerItem = listenerIterator.previous();
            EventListener<Event> listenerRef = listenerItem.get();
            if (listenerRef != null) {
                listenerRef.onEvent(event);
            } else {
                listenerIterator.remove();
            }
        }

    …
}
```

use case

```
EventListener<Event> mEventListener = new EventListener<Event>(
        Event.class) {
    @Override
    public boolean onEvent(Event event) {
        eMgr.removeListener(mEventListener);
        // do something
    }
};

addEventListener(mEventListener);
```

in dispatchEvent(), while it is in the loop the removeListener() is called and causes the ConcurrentModificationException at listenerItem = listenerIterator.previous();

question: what is the best way to avoid the crash caused by the change of the mEventMap data while someone is iterating on it.

Comment: One way would be to copy the list without the element you want to remove... Like CopyOnWriteArrayList

Comment: First of all, the idea of holding weak references to listeners is the perfect way to shoot yourself in the foot. That requires someone else to hold a strong reference to the listener to prevent spurious disappearance of listeners. In usual application design, there is no one holding such required references and anonymous listener instances are the norm. Then, once you abandon the idea of weak references, have a look at the design pattern behind `AWTEventMulticaster` which provides a robust way of event delivery, immune to in-between additions and removals (without the need to clone a list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach to choose is to add a flag in the listener object, 'isRemoved'. So the removeListener would only mark this listener has been moved, but it will stay in the list until the dispatch time which will only dispatch to the ones not marked. And all marked ones will be removed from list after the dispatch loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you want to remove an element from the list **while** traversing it with an implicit iterator.

You could solve that by using explicitly an iterator:

```
for (Iterator<EventListener> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    EventListener el = it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks m4mbax, it did the same: ListIterator<WeakReference<EventListener<Event>>> listenerIterator = listeners.listIterator(listeners.size());
the problem is node was removed while the iterator is still traversing.

Answer (score 1):

Create a safe copy of your list in `dispatchEvent` before the loop something like:

```
List<WeakReference<EventListener<Event>>> listeners 
                          = new ArrayList<>(mEventMap.get(event.getClass()));
```

But by far the best approach for listeners is to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` to manage the list of listeners as you don't modify it too often and it is already thread safe such that you don't need any `synchronized blocks` anymore.

Comment: thanks Nicolas! will take a look at CopyOnWriteArrayList. Making copy to work on would help, but does not prevent the listener to be removed from different thread and in the working copy will still call into the removed ones.

Comment: don't forget that you are in a synchronized block so only one thread can execute those critical sections so I don't believe that your use case is possible unless you forgot to protect it elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use java's built in EventListenerList class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html.  Although it is in the javax.swing packages, I've found it very useful for event notification in general.  It is backed by an array, manages listeners by class, and does not throw concurrent mod exceptions.  Firing an event is done like so:

```
Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
    for(int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2){
        if(listeners[i] == YourListenerClass.class){
            ((YourListenerClass)listeners[i + 1]).yourListenerMethod(yourEvent);
        }

    }
```